# ng-options skip the first element

Tags: angularjs

How can i force from ng-options to skip the first element?

i tried: `ng-show="!$first"` which works on ng-repeat but it's not working on ng-options

this is my code:

```
<select data-ng-model="minutes_per_slot" data-ng-options="slot as slot + ' minutes' for slot in all_slots"></select>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.all_slots = ["00","5","10","15","20","25"];
```

i want no option contains the 00, but i can't remove it from the array.

any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<select data-ng-model="minutes_per_slot" data-ng-options="slot as slot + ' minutes' for slot in all_slots.slice(1)"></select>
```

Almost the same code, but makes a selection with `slice` to get everything after the first element. Also still uses `ng-options`, not option repeating, which is usually an issue in older IE versions.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/yolig/1/edit

```
 <select data-ng-model="minutes_per_slot" >
    <option ng-repeat="slot in all_slots" value="{{slot}}" ng-if="slot!='00'" >{{slot}} minutes </option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-repeat on options tag like this

```
<select data-ng-model="minutes_per_slot">

<option ng-repeat="currentSlot in all_slots" value="slot" ng-if="currentSlot !== '00'" >{{currentSlot}} minutes </option>

</select>
```